# Exclude _id field during a join query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I try to create a join query and exclude _id field from my result

```
    stage_lookup_comments = {
        "$lookup": {
                "from": "products",
                "localField": "product_codename",
                "foreignField": "codename",
                "as": "product",
        }

    }

    pipeline = [
        { "$match": {
            "category":category,
            "archived_at":{"$eq": None}
            }
        },
        stage_lookup_comments
        ]

    array = await db[collection].aggregate(pipeline).to_list(CURSOR_LIMIT)
    return array
```

I don't know what is the syntax to add the `"_id": 0` parameter to my query.

Comment: How about adding one more `$project` stage at the end to exclude the `_id` field through `_id: false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use MongoDB `$project` in your pipeline to select only those fields you want to return. In this particular case you can exclude `_id` field as you already mentioned putting `_id:0`.

Read documentation about `$project` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) for more details.

I didn't test it, but your query should be something similar to the following:

```
stage_lookup_comments = {
        "$lookup": {
                "from": "products",
                "localField": "product_codename",
                "foreignField": "codename",
                "as": "product",
        }

    }

    pipeline = [
        { 
          "$match": {
             "category":category,
             "archived_at":{"$eq": None}
           }
        },
        stage_lookup_comments,
        { 
           $project: { "_id": 0 } 
        }

    ]

    array = await db[collection].aggregate(pipeline).to_list(CURSOR_LIMIT)
    return array
```

**EDIT**:

Also, starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can use operator `$unset` to explicitly remove a field from a document (see documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-unset)):

```
{ $unset: ["_id"] }
```

You can read more about this in [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776453/how-to-hide-id-from-aggregation) here on Stackoverflow.
I hope this works!